# How to reference Microsoft.Boogie when compiling with Mono?

Tags: c#, mono

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Boogie;

public class Trace
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 2){
        return;
    }
    Program program = new Program();
    List<string> defines = new List<string>();
    Parser.Parse(args[0], defines, out program);
    
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(args[1]);
    Dictionary< Block, List<Block> > adj = new Dictionary< Block, List<Block> >();
    
    foreach (Declaration D in program.TopLevelDeclarations){
        Implementation I = D as Implementation;
        if(I != null){
            foreach (Block B in I.Blocks){
                object cmd = B.TransferCmd;
                if(cmd is GotoCmd){
                    List<Block> target = cmd.labelTargets;
                    adj.insert(B, target);
                }
                else if(cmd is ReturnCmd){
                    adj.insert(B, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am new to C# and I am stuck on how to iterate over `program.TopLevelDeclarations`.

Trying to iterate over a simple list works but when I try to include the [Microsoft Boogie](http://boogie.codeplex.com/releases/view/96678) library, the compiler throws a few errors.

I am compiling my program using `gmcs` on Ubuntu 13.04 using the command:

```
gmcs -r:../../boogie/Binaries/Boogie.exe -r:../../boogie/Binaries/Core.dll Trace.cs
```

Which gives the following errors:

> Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/boogie/Binaries/Core.dll, type System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractClassAttribute
>
> Can`t find custom attr constructor image: /home/boogie/Binaries/Core.dll mtoken: 0x0a000463
>
> - Trace.cs(19,52): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not load type `System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractClassAttribute` from assembly `Core`.
> - Trace.cs(19,36): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `object` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.Boogie.Declaration>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> - Trace.cs(22,30): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `Microsoft.Boogie.Implementation` from `Core, Version=2.2.30705.1126, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16`
> - Trace.cs(22,30): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `object` to `bool`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> - Trace.cs(23,55): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `Microsoft.Boogie.Implementation` from `Core, Version=2.2.30705.1126, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16`
> - Trace.cs(23,33): error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `object` because it does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator` or is inaccessible
>
> Compilation failed: 6 error(s), 0 warnings

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I including the libraries incorrectly?

Comment: Are the libraries on your machine? Are you using the Mono framework? Also, if you're on Ubuntu, you could be using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download) rather than compiling by hand, which would take care of most of these issues for you.

Comment: yes, i am using MonoDevelop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to find the source of `Microsoft.Boogie.Declaration`, but given the error messages it has a `[ContractClass]` attribute, which the compiler cannot find:

> Trace.cs(19,52): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractClassAttribute' from assembly 'Core'.

Because of this the type `Microsoft.Boogie.Declaration` cannot be loaded, causing the  `List<Declaration>` of `program.TopLevelDeclarations` to apparently be "stubbed" of some sort as an `object`. This in turn causes *your* code to fail, because you can't iterate over an object.

The [`ContractClassAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractclassattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was added to `mscorlib` in .NET 4. You're using `gmcs`, which according to [mono's CSharp Compiler manual page](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) compiles against .NET 2.0.

I think you better compile using `mcs`, which is recommended there.